# Is it okay to add a lecturer on LinkedIn

Tags: social-media

I'm a graduate student and I recently attended a course by a very inspiring lecturer (associate professor).
Do you think it is okay add him on LinkedIn? Do I push him into an uncomfortable situation by doing that?

Comment: Have you finished the course or not? If yes, then there should be no problem, if no and you feel like you are pushing him then you can wait till the end of course - semester etc. Facebook on the other hand.....

Comment: Yes, i've already finished the course.

Comment: I wouldn't say he would have an issue, I've actually done it a few times; everyone is different - but what do you have to lose!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not believe an educator would feel they were put in an uncomfortable position by a student sending a LinkedIn request.

You should not, however, expect that the lecturer will accept your request. Some lecturers like to be very close to their students. Personally, I like to keep a professional distance from my students, even after they graduate. Of course, if a student happens to share a common area of research as me and wants to work together, that would be different but I certainly do not accept many requests to "connect" to students, even after they graduate.

What you should avoid is sending multiple requests or following up in person "Hey, did you get my 'quest? It would be super-kul if you'd add me." If they want to connect they will. If not, they will just consider you a student who is interested in having a closer connection than they want and they will ignore it.

Either way, I do not believe any lecturer would be made uncomfortable by your gesture of interest.

Comment: "You should not, however, expect that the lecturer will accept your request" is the key point.  Everyone's standards for contacts is different.  One may accept, another may not.  Do not be afraid to ask.  Do not be offended if you're not accepted, it's generally not personal, you may simply not fit the requirements.