# Add supervisor on social media

Tags: phd, advisor, masters

Is it weird to add the master's thesis supervisor or have any contact/like their posts etc on social media if the supervisor is a PhD student? What about after they finish their PhD?

Comment: Are you talking about Parler or LinkedIn here, or something in between?

Comment: Like facebook, instagram etc

Comment: Some groups have a twitter account (e.g. [Baran group at Scripps](https://twitter.com/BaranLabReads), [Penteleute group at MIT](https://twitter.com/PenteluteLab)) equally about results and achievements of present/previous lab members.  It is probably more a question if the person accepts this (depends a bit on culture and how you interact with each other, of course), and considers facebook/instagram as a professional or more private venue.

Comment: This question is somewhat similar, maybe it will yield some answers that you might find helpfull https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149880/is-it-acceptable-for-a-student-to-connect-with-a-professor-on-linkedin